# Accessing/Manipulating content scripts through console in Google Chrome/Firefox Addon

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Through google chrome's console and Mozilla Firefox's Web Console we can access/manipulate javascript state of any page. But is it possible to access content scripts running in isolated worlds in google chrome and in Mozilla Firefox. If yes then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking about inspecting extensions, you can do that in Chrome from the Extension Preferences window (Wrench > Tools > Extensions > Developer mode, then click the triangle next to the extension, and look under "Inspect active views").

For Firefox, try Venkman.

Comment: I think this feature is not available in chrome 13.x

Comment: It is not. Chrome 17 is the latest stable version and you should update to it.